# Disposing and closing windows in Java

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

Okay, so this might be a stupid question, but I'm new to Java and trying to teach myself things the right way before I develop any bad habits.

Anyway, I was writing a program last night that consisted of a custom class extending Frame and a custom class extending Canvas. The main() method is in the canvas class and I create an instance of the frame class there. The problem is that when the program detects a window close event, I can't dispose the frame because I seemingly have no way to access it from outside the main method. And if I try to define it outside of main(), then I can't use it within. So I ended up skipping dispose() and just using System.exit(0). Is this alright? Is it basically doing the same thing anyway? Or is this a problem I need to fix, and if so, any idea how?

Thanks so much for reading,

Cody

Comment: System.exit(0)  terminates the running JVM so be careful about that. It may be not just your application running inside that jvm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get a reference to the frame, from the `source` property of the event:

```
class MyWindowListener extends WindowAdapter {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
         Frame frame = (Frame) e.getSource();
         frame.dispose();
    }

}
```

Alternatively, since this is an anonymous class (presumably) declared within the constructor, you also have access to the enclosing instance, so you can also write it as:

```
class MyFrameClass extends Frame {
    public MyFrameClass() {
        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                 MyFrameClass.this.dispose();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Or you can make it simpler still (as your WindowListener does not have a method of its own called "dispose"):

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
     dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. That makes a lot more sense. Never occurred to me to cast the output of getSource as a frame and use that.

Answer (score 5):

Not a stupid question. Because of  the garbage collector its not such a big issue, however, there are some times when you will want to execute some cleanup when a window closes. So some suggestions:

The Window Closing event should be handled from the Frame itself. For instance:

```
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                  //code here to perform as the window is about to close.
         }
        });
```

And I would suggest that you create a separate class for your main method that will invoke the Frame etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I will try using a separate class for my main method. Seems much cleaner that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is used to  close Jframe  with an event handler.


current Jframe 

public class LoginForm  extends JFrame
{

   LoginForm()
   {
      //Some code for Jframe and its components.
      if(Condition)
        disposewindow();
   }




private void disposewindow()
      {
          WindowEvent closingEvent = new WindowEvent(LoginForm.this,
                                                           WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING);
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemEventQueue().postEvent(closingEvent);

      }



//you can  can use for alternate of dispose()event  and it post some event handler **Closing event** ,

// if we can use  this closing event to open new window with conditions.

//It means closing child window with closing event, get this flag in main window to make main window as Disable or Enable state
```

}

//In parent window
    @Override

```
 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.frame.disable();
    }
```